# Bootstrap 3.3.2 > Dropdown menu > jQuery function

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a multi dropdown menu what works only with clicks... 
If I make a 2 level menu it works okey, one click to show, another click to hide. But If I make a 3 or 4 level menu this shows, but on another click doesn hide the submenu...

this is the test, how to hide the submenu on click on the parent? [work menu][1]

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/mmtx0zph/2/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `toggleClass` method from jQuery -

```
 $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    // Avoid following the href location when clicking
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // Avoid having the menu to close when clicking
    event.stopPropagation();
    // opening the one you clicked on
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmtx0zph/9/)